# Ocaml recursion not printing int when inside another Function

Tags: ocaml

When I compile and Execute this piece of code. It prints nothing.

```
 let main list = 
        let rec xyz list = 
            match list with
            |[]->[]
            |m::body -> 
            begin
            print_int m;
            xyz body 
            end
        in xyz
    
    let h = main [1;2;3]
```

If **xyz** is used outside of main is working without any error and printing 1 2 and 3

Comment: Why would it? You're not running the inner function. I bet you're also getting a warning about an unused value. You should heed that warning and either use the returned value or explicitly ignore it with a type annotation. That would give you a much more useful error.

Comment: @glennsl, what command are you using to display all the warnings?

Comment: On the command line, you can use `-w +A`, if you are using ocamlc or ocamlopt directly. In the file itself adding `[@@@warning "+A"]` at the top of the file will be equivalent. And Dune has a better set of warning enabled by default.

Comment: The `unused-var` warning is enabled by default, so you shouldn't need to do anything. Turning on all warnings isn't a bad idea though. Or even `-warn-error +A` to turn them into errors.

Comment: The `unused-var` warning doesn't warn for function arguments, only for unused variable bound by a `let` or with `as`. This mistake is only detected by its stricter version `unused-var-strict` which is disabled by default in the compiler.

Comment: @octachron Ah, I was originally referring to the `h` variable though, which also does not seem to be used as its type is not what one would expect from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your code with all warning enabled yields the following warning:

```
1 | let main list =
             ^^^^
Warning 27 [unused-var-strict]: unused variable list.
```

And indeed, the argument `list` is unused by `main` since in

```
let main list =
  let rec xyz list =
    ...
  in
  xyz
```

you are returning the function `xyz` without applying it.

Comment: You need to use the `list` argument of `main`.

Comment: Indeed, this is one of the solution.